# Increased "First Load JS" Size After Adding Sentry to Next.js 13.4.10 Blueprint App

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sentry, next.js13

I have developed a Next.js blueprint app for testing purposes, using Next.js version 13.4.10. Recently, I integrated Sentry into the project to monitor errors and performance. However, I noticed a significant increase in the "First Load JS" size after incorporating Sentry. Here is the output from the Next.js build after adding  sentry yo blueprint app:
[image]

I'm concerned about the increase in the "First Load JS" size and its potential impact on the application's performance. As a result, I would like to understand the reasons behind this increase and explore any possible optimizations or adjustments I can make to mitigate it.
Specifically, I have the following questions:
Is it expected to see an increase in the "First Load JS" size when incorporating Sentry into a Next.js 13.4.10 project?
Are there any specific configuration options or best practices to optimize the bundle size when using Sentry in Next.js 13.4.10?
Are there any particular dependencies or features of Sentry that might contribute to the increased "First Load JS" size?

Here's how I imported Sentry into my Next.js app:

```
const { withSentryConfig , init} = require("@sentry/nextjs");
```

Comment: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/9179#issuecomment-1748962273